# Linq Filter Posts by list of Tags

Tags: linq

```
public class LogItemTag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Tagname { get; set; }
}

var logItemTags = new List<LogItemTag>();
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 1, TagName = "red" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 1, TagName = "green" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 3, TagName = "blue" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 3, TagName = "red" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 4, TagName = "green" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 6, TagName = "white" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 7, TagName = "red" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 7, TagName = "green" });

var listOfTagsToFilterOn = new List<string> {"red", "green" };

//I need a list of ids 1 and 7 only.

//this query produces 6 ids - 1,1,3,4,7,7
var query = logItemTags.Where(lit => listOfTagsToFilterOn.Contains(lit.TagName)).Select(lit => lit.ID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Contains` extension method:

```
var tags=new List<string>(){"red", "green"};// the collection of tags you want to get the ids
var query=LogItemTagList.Where(l=>tags.Contains(l.Tagname)).Select(l=>l.ID);
```

### Update 1

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
var query=LogItemTagList.Where(l=>tags.Contains(l.Tagname))
                        .GroupBy(l=>l.ID)
                        .Where(g=>g.Count==tags.Count)
                        .Select(g=>g.Key)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, please see comment in hamlet's post

Comment: @octaviocci Thanks.  I only want to see LogItems that have Both red AND green.  Not red OR green.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Terrence, but that is a different question you asked for, please could you clarify what are you trying to achieve? `LogItem` is another class of your model that has a list of `LogItemTags`, is that right?

Comment: @Terrence, I think that now I understand what you are trying to achieve, take a look

Comment: octaviocci thanks for your help.  That is what I was looking for.  How do I mark your answer as the correct answer?

Comment: @Terrence, below of my votes you will see an arrow, you need to mark it

Answer (score 2):

Use [Enumerable.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method

```
var filterList = new [] {"red", "green"};
var list = new List<LogItemTag>
       {
             new LogItemTag {ID =1; TagName = "green"},
             ....
       };

var filteredIds = list.Where(i => filterList.Contains(i.TagName)
                  .Select(f => f.ID).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

```
List<LogItemTag> logItemTags = new List<LogItemTag>();
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 1, TagName = "red" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 1, TagName = "green" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 3, TagName = "blue" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 3, TagName = "red" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 4, TagName = "green" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 6, TagName = "white" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 7, TagName = "red" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 7, TagName = "green" });

var listOfTagsToFilterOn = new List<string> {"red", "green" };

var filteredList = logItemTags.Where(l => listOfTagsToFilterOn.Contains(l.TagName))
    .GroupBy(l => l.ID,
             l => l.TagName,
             (k, t) => new {Id = k, Count = t.Distinct().Count()})
    .Where(d => d.Count == listOfTagsToFilterOn.Count())
    .Select(d => d.Id).ToList();
```

Here some explanation

First we group the data by ID and generate objects of anonymous type with ID and distinct count of tags. Then filter them to match tag counts to filter tags count. This will work either you have set the same tag to sme ID.

Comment: This produces a list of 1, 5 and 6.  So it is inclusive instead of filtering.  The only ids that has both is 1 and 6

Comment: Hamlet thank you for your help.  Now I have 3 solutions.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I would do it. Feel free to edit it / optimize it.

```
var logItemTags = new List<LogItemTag>();
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 1, TagName = "red" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 1, TagName = "green" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 3, TagName = "blue" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 3, TagName = "red" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 4, TagName = "green" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 6, TagName = "white" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 7, TagName = "red" });
logItemTags.Add(new LogItemTag { ID = 7, TagName = "green" });

var listOfTagsToFilterOn = new List<string> {"red", "green" };

var list = logItemTags.Where(
    x => listOfTagsToFilterOn.All(
    y => logItemTags.Any(
    z => z.ID == x.ID && y.TagName == z.TagName)))
    .Select(x => x.ID).Distinct();
```

Select all ids that passes all filters (where an item has all tagnames)

Comment: Etienne thank you for your help, this linq works a well.